# Error while converting varchar to bigint

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am executing the below query. In the query ChID is not the column of Cat table. For that I am placing 0 as ChID and converting it to bigint datatype to match with the column's datatype of CatAtt. But I am getting the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

I have executed similar query in Oracle with Oracle related changes and I got the results.

```
WITH rg (ID, ChID, Name) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        CAST(0 AS bigint) ChID,
        Name
    FROM Cat
    WHERE ID = 1000

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        c.ID,
        c.ChID,
        k.Name
    FROM CatAtt c
    JOIN rg p ON (c.ChID = p.ID)
    JOIN Cat k ON (c.ID = k.ID)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    ka.ID
FROM 
    rg, Parent app
JOIN 
    Cat ka ON (ka.ID = app.UserIdentifier)
JOIN 
    Owner dt ON (dt.ID = app.ID)
WHERE 
    app.ID = 25773
    AND app.aprroved = 0
    AND REPLACE(ka.Name, ka.Type + '_', dt.OwnerID + '_') = rg.Name
```

Comment: What data type is `CatAtt.ChID`?  That may be the one with the problem.

Comment: data type of CatAtt.ChID is bigint.

Comment: One of your joins has a `VARCHAR` value that isn't numeric. I'm guessing `app.UserIdentifier`. You can find out which one buy using `TRY_CONVERT()` for SQL Server 2012+. Otherwise you'll have to dig a little deeper since `ISNUMERIC` can be iffy if you don't understand it well. So try something like `select UserIdentifier from Parent where TRY_CONVERT(bigint,UserIdentifier) is null`

Comment: First of all you should use ANSI-92 style joins instead the old comma separated list. And most importantly you should NOT mix the two styles in a single query. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Convert instead of cast

```
WITH rg (ID, ChID, Name) AS 
(
SELECT
    ID,
    CONVERT(bigint , '0') ChID,
    Name
FROM Cat
WHERE ID = 1000

UNION ALL

SELECT
    c.ID,
    c.ChID,
    k.Name
FROM CatAtt c
JOIN rg p ON (c.ChID = p.ID)
JOIN Cat k ON (c.ID = k.ID)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
ka.ID
FROM 
rg, Parent app
JOIN 
Cat ka ON (ka.ID = app.UserIdentifier)
JOIN 
Owner dt ON (dt.ID = app.ID)
WHERE 
app.ID = 25773
AND app.aprroved = 0
AND REPLACE(ka.Name, cast((ka.Type) as nvarchar(max)) + '_', cast((dt.OwnerID as nvarchar(max)) + '_')) = rg.Name
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this will make any difference? The error message is about converting a varchar to bigint.

Comment: so i think that "convert(bigint , '0')chID" will convert Zero to bigint

Comment: Yeah, I verified the once again and found that the error is at Replace method where ka.Name is nvarchar and not null, ka.type is bigint and not null, dt.ownerid is bigint and not null. In oracle the syntax is "REPLACE(ka.Name, ka.Type || '_', dt.ownerid || '_') = rg.Name"  which worked and got results. I verified in SQL by removing the Replace method and executed, results got displayed and when I keep the condition, I am getting the error.

Comment: @Ashu that is correct but it is NOT the issue the OP is having. Their code is casting a 0 to a bigint. There is no varchar in that. The error is elsewhere in their code.

Comment: @Sean i got your point, and now i have made changes in REPLACE function which was giving error earlier

Comment: @Pathan is it woking now?